# python open directory error

Tags: image, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Wrote some code to go through a folder of 200 images to get the value of the minimum number of pixels in an image  (i.e. min  width and height)

But I keep getting this error :

```
File "pixelSizeCheck.py", line 9, in get_num_pixels
width, height = Image.open(open(filepath)).size
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory:
```

when I run this code :

```
from PIL import Image
import os.path

def get_num_pixels(filepath):
    heightMin= 10000
    widthMin= 10000
    for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg") :
            width, height = Image.open(open(filepath)).size
            if width< widthMin:
                widthMin = width
                return widthMin

            if height < heightMin:
                heightMin = height
                return heightMin

print (heightMin, widthMin)

get_num_pixels("filepath")
```

However i have tested the code with print statement and i know the directory i have been putting in is correct because it reaches the for loop correctly but then crashes when i try and won line 9 :

```
Image.open(open(filepath)).size
```

also I'm relatively new to python so any advice on how to improve the code would be much appreciated. Apologies in advance if any of the code is sloppy or poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're trying to open the directory you're scanning: In `Image.open` call:

```
open(filepath)
```

should be (the second error is that you have to open in binary mode too)

```
open(os.path.join(filepath,filename),"rb")
```

a better way would be to use `glob.glob` to filter *and* get absolute path at the same time:

```
for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") :
        width, height = Image.open(open(os.path.join(filepath,filename),"rb")).size
```

would become (with, added, a context manager to make sure the file is closed):

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(filepath,"*.jpg")):
    with open(filename,"rb") as f:
        width, height = Image.open(f).size
```

Comment: if  i use glob i keep getting this weird error   File "pixelSizeCheck.py", line 10, in get_num_pixels
    width, height = Image.open(f).size
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2419, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: sorry, there was another issue: you have to open the file as binary.

Comment: How do i open the file in binary ? sorry new to python